# Icon stops loading after the application restarts

Tags: linux, shell, .desktop

I have a application which uses "self-restart" mechanism. It kills itself and runs again. When I run it first time (with `.desktop` file) it loads its icon correctly. The problem is that when it restarts itself, it runs its binary and not the `.desktop` file. The result is that it does not load the icon. I was thinking about sending the path to `.desktop` as an argument of the application and running that instead of the binary.

I would like to ask if it is possible to use the path to `.desktop` file as the argument for my application inside the same `.desktop` file.

Or is there a another way that will keep the icon loaded?

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyApp
Exec=myBinary *PathToThisDesktopFile*
Type=Application
Icon=my_icon.png
```

Comment: Could you give us a use case scenario? I can't imagine why you would want to do this. What binary would you want to run on the .desktop file itself?

Comment: @terdon I've edited the quesiton.

Comment: OK, this sounds like a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please [edit] some more and explain exactly where you see this icon, what kind of application you have etc. Make it clear that your objective is to have your icon appear/load whatever, no matter how your application is launched. I'm fairly certain that fiddling with the .desktop file's path is not the way to do it.

Comment: @terdon Done. I hope it's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Might be helpful (a snippet from netbeans launcher):

```
~> cat ~/.local/share/applications/netbeans-8.0.desktop|grep Exec
Exec=/bin/sh "/home/ipip/opt/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans"
```

Comment: That does not solve/show anything...

Comment: Oh, I see now... I answered a completley different question :-)

Comment: Then, you'll have to tell the application, not to start its binary but the .desktop file. I'm pretty sure, it determines it's path and executable from some environment variables or argv, so putting reference to .desktop file to the `Exec` enty is probably not the way.